# Why date and touch/stat return different time value?

Tags: linux, time

In my system SLES 11.2, I get strange output for file access time.
The **date** command output the correct time:

Then I create a new file "a" by running **touch**, and use **stat** to check the access time of file "a".

```
1)   date
Wed Mar 19 11:17:43 EST 2014

2) touch a

3) stat a
  File: `a'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 32768  regular empty file
Device: 19h/25d Inode: 2168864     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( )   Gid: ( )
Access: 2014-03-19 07:00:40.277402670 +1100
Modify: 2014-03-19 07:00:40.277402670 +1100
Change: 2014-03-19 07:00:40.277402670 +1100
 Birth: -
```

Can anyone tells me what's causing the difference?

Comment: BTW, what type of filesystem is this?

Comment: I found out the reason, the /home is a NFS mounted directory on this host. The time on the NFS server is not correct.

Comment: Glad you figured out out.  You can self-answer your question and mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Something is weird about your timezone configuration.  [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (Eastern Standard time) is usually `-500` or `-400` for daylight savings time. Your stat seems to be showing a value for `+1100` -or +11 hours.

Comment: It's Australian EST, also displayed as EST.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I would answer the question my elf.

I ran the commands on the host under the /home directory, which is a NFS mounted directory. However, the time on the NFS server is not correct. Which results in the file changed took the wrong time from the NFS server.